# Can all of physics be described by simple math?

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity, mathematics

Recently I was browsing through [A Dynamical Theory of electromagnetic field](http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/155/459) by Maxwell and wondered because the paper did not seem to include any vector calculus or any vectors. I thought of the famous paper by Einstein [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf) and couldn't find any vector calculus either. Instead he writes out every component separately. Although the papers didn't include more (sophisticated) math they were able to describe the physical phenomena very well.

This led me to the question if not more physical problems could be reduced to simpler math (for example just calculus) but still be able to describe the physics in the same way.

So would one be able to describe whole physical fields such as Quantum Mechanics without Linear Algebra or Relativity without Tensor algebra?

Or maybe you know any examples where the further mathematics is essential for the correct description of physics?

Comment: Math is the language of physics. Can you communicate about physics without that language? Sure. You can also give a thirty second synopsis of "War and Peace" in sign language. Is that the same thing as reading the full novel?

Comment: I am not asking if one can describe physics without math. I am asking if one can describe physics by tracing the math back to the basics.

Comment: Can you replace every word in "War and Peace" with its definition from a dictionary? Sure. Is that going to be good reading material? Nope.

Comment: To be honest with you, I think you have a somewhat good question there, you are just totally missing the point. Physics has two languages: experiment and theory. Experiments are the expression of hypotheses in terms of physical machines. Theory is the collection of reasonable hypotheses that have some predictive value for the construction of said machines and the explanation of observed natural phenomena. The art of physics is the constant interplay between the two.

Comment: The whole reason that modern treatments have displaced the notation of, e.g. Maxwell and Einstein is that the modern treatments are simpler.

Comment: This almost sounds like you're asking, "Can I be a (theoretical?) physicist without knowing beyond vector calculus?" which is possible, but why shy away from *useful* mathematics?

Comment: The fact that the notation used has changed over time does not mean that the math used in those papers was 'simple' - they just didn't use current vector calculus notation. Similarly, Rutherford's papers can be hard to read since the notation has changed, but that doesn't invalidate the Rutherford Backscattering cross section derivation.

Comment: you can translate any mathematical theory into set theory. It will be painful and unintuitive, but you can describe all physics and math in terms of sets

Comment: @WillO: While reading Copernicus I noticed how he was basically inventing rather modern ideas (like sine/cosine tables and interpolation) that seem very natural to us, but each time he had to add many sentences and sometimes entire chapters to convince himself that his ideas where both working and worthwhile. I think one could say the same thing about Maxwell's and Einstein's papers. We know that their ideas work, so we can leave out all the fluff. In the future kids will probably learn concepts from differential geometry in middle school, which will allow a reformulation of physics textbooks.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  Agreed, absolutely.

Comment: @brucesmitherson:  I am skeptical that any mathematical theory can be translated into set theory.  Take, for example, the theory of the category of all small categories.  I agree with your larger point, but I don't think "set theory" is quite correct here.

Comment: @WillO agreed! but set theory still cover at least all standard math used in physics

Comment: All math can be described by simple math.

Comment: @brucesmitherson:  Agreed re math used in physics.

Comment: If you follow the equivalence principle and reverse the vectors, you can solve GR problems very quickly with basic maths. Tensors become just fancy dressing.

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about answering or not this one. I am not sure if I should... But well, I'll give a try.

Well... The whole math is "backtracable" to more primitive structures, because all the more advanced structures is defined based on the simpler one.

For instance: you can write an derivative using differential calculus. But you can also write a derivative using limits, because the definition of a derivative is a limit. You can also write a limit as a norm, because definition of a limit is based on norm (Note that we are writing a derivative not even using differential calculus). But it won't stop... what is a norm? Its definition is based on a function... What is a function? Its a ordered triple of two sets and a map. Ordered triple is a ordered pair of a number and a ordered pair. Ordered pair is defined as a set. Now one can write a derivative using maps (set operation) and sets (Very primitive isn't it?). Here, behold the derivative of a function $f'(x_0) = L$ using norms:

$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \quad\exists\delta>0, \quad\mbox{st}\quad 
0<\left|x - x_0\right|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - L\right|<\epsilon
$$

So.. this is a derivative.. not even using differential calculus. But then, what is simpler? $\frac{df}{dx}$? or that? Which one is more readable? Well.. I tend to think differential calculus is simpler, instead of this norm stuff: Try to calculate the derivative of $f(x) = x$ using calculus, and using this norm stuff. =).

Same way, since the whole math is based on set theory (not sure about that, I am not a mathematician), then probably you can reduce everything from math and eventually from physics into more primitive stuffs, and keep doing until arrive in sets and set operations. But it wouldn't be readable. And would be big. That's where comes modern notation. Its not to overcomplicate, its to simplify.

Comment: What you are talking about are called "levels of abstraction".  Real analysis is an abstraction that can be built upon set theory.  Complex analysis extends real analysis.  The algebra of fields generalizes complex analysis.  Linear algebra is build upon the algebra of scalar fields, and so on, and so on.  Each of these ideas "abstracts away" details of the layer below that do not contribute to an understanding of whatever problem at hand.

Comment: Very true. I think some mathematicians may somewhat disagree about set theory being simple. It's all but, thankfully the hard parts are not needed for what physicists do (all our systems are finite or can be approximated with well behaved infinite sets).

Comment: Should your implication be the other way around?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance It should. Thanks. It also should not include the zero.. I'll fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Writing equations in vector rather than component form makes thinking and writing easier, but as you surmise doesn't lead to new physics.  However, some "more complicated math" really does explain new phenomena.

For example, are calculus and Schrodinger's differential equation sufficient for explaining the energy levels of the hydrogen atom?  Separating the equation into a radial and angular part, we find the energies are specified by a radial integer n=1,2,... , and an angular momentum integer $l=0,1,2,...n-1$ (and its z component $l_z=-l,-l+1,...,0,...l$).  But the hydrogen atom actually has more energy levels which the half-integer spins of the electron and proton are needed to explain.  You need a new mathematical construct, the Lie Group SU(2), to explain the existence of half-integer spin angular momenta... calculus by itself was not sufficient.  The Dirac equation needs the Pauli spin matrices satisfying the algebra of SU(2).

While perhaps it is true that a mathematician may formally build up to Lie Groups from set theory and numbers, new ideas were introduced along the way, and some have been useful to physics.